# Custom inheritance rules not working with biblatex

Tags: biblatex, xetex, biber

I work on a document (XeLaTeX), where many mixed language collections are cited. Using `biblatex` I can make use of the hyphenation field to switch between different languages (although the `babel`-option doesn't work completely with the `polyglossia` package, but that's another story).

However, due to the publishing guidelines I need both information: the language of the article itself as well as the language of the collected work. Therefore I add an inheritance rule to `biblatex`.

```
\DeclareDataInheritance{collection}{incollection}{
   \inherit{hyphenation}{bookhyphenation}}%
```

This rule is correctly transferred into the "biblatex control file" (bcf):

```xml
<bcf:inherit>
  <bcf:type_pair source="collection" target="incollection"/>
  <bcf:field source="hyphenation" target="bookhyphenation"/>
</bcf:inherit>
```

I then want to look for different field values with `\iffieldundef`. In order to show the problem I tried to create an example by adding a `\newbibmacro` and modifiying the bibliography driver.

```
\newbibmacro*{printhyphenation}{%
   \iffieldundef{bookhyphenation}{No book hyphenation field}{Book hyphenation: \printfield{bookhyphenation}}%
   \addcomma\space
   \iffieldundef{hyphenation}{No hyphenation field}{Hyphenation: \printfield{hyphenation}}%
}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{incollection}{%
   \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
   \usebibmacro{begentry}%
   \usebibmacro{author/translator+others}%
   \setunit{\labelnamepunct}\newblock%
   \usebibmacro{title}%
   \addcomma\space
   \usebibmacro{printhyphenation}
}
```

As you can see from the resulting PDF the book `hyphenation` field is always empty, so no complex if-clauses etc. are possible.

Does anyone have an idea how to solve my problem?

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
   @collection{A,
      title = {Title},
      editor = {Y, X},
      hyphenation = {english}
   }
   @incollection{B,
      crossref = {A},
      title = {Title},
      author = {B, A},
      hyphenation = {german}
   }
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{polyglossia} %XeLaTeX document
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage[spelling=new,latesthyphen,babelshorthands]{german}

\usepackage[autostyle,babel]{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=authoryear-comp,babel=other,backend=biber]{biblatex}
% Add an inheritance rule
\DeclareDataInheritance{collection}{incollection}{
\inherit{hyphenation}{bookhyphenation}}%

\addbibresource{\jobname}

\newbibmacro*{printhyphenation}{%
   \iffieldundef{bookhyphenation}{No book hyphenation field}{Book hyphenation: \printfield{bookhyphenation}}%
   \addcomma\space
   \iffieldundef{hyphenation}{No hyphenation field}{Hyphenation: \printfield{hyphenation}}%
}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{incollection}{%
   \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
   \usebibmacro{begentry}%
   \usebibmacro{author/translator+others}%
   \setunit{\labelnamepunct}\newblock%
   \usebibmacro{title}%
   \addcomma\space
   \usebibmacro{printhyphenation}
}    

\begin{document}
foo \cite{B} bar \cite{A}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: `bookhyphenation` isn't a field in `biblatex`'s data model. Recognized fields are listed in the manual's database guide. You could use `hyphenation` or one of the custom fields (e.g. `usera`, `userb`, etc.) instead.

Comment: I might be mad, but I thought that if one was trying to have some record of the language which would be used in output, the "correct" thing was to place that in the `language` datafield (which is a list, I think, and can therefore accommodate collections with multiple languages). Hyphenation is intended to assist internally in setting a particular entry's details, not for external consumption. If your collections are mixed language, you surely need a field that can accommodate more than one language.

Comment: Yes, it will appear in the `.bcf` but biber will ignore it when processing inheritance because `bookhyphenation` is not a valid biblatex data field. You could inherit it as `usera` etc. and check it there though. In the future, the data model will be user-definable. This is already possible in biber which uses a modular data model already internally. biblatex will get an interface to this soon.

Comment: @PaulStanley The language field sums up the used languages of a work, but for getting different lanuage-dependent terms like "editor" vs. "Herausgeber" or "volume" vs. "Band" the hyphenation field is used via the babel-option.

Therefore I tried to use "bookhyphenation" to continue this concept. I will now try "usera" as suggested.

Comment: @Martin I see. But that may be trickier, because you'll not only need to inherit that field, but also tell biblatex how to use it. So you'll need to fiddle with internals to tell biblatex to use the hyphenation language for some purposes, and usera for others. If most language-specific stuff usually comes from the book, not the component sub-part, you may be better off setting hyphenation from the main book, since usera may well be only really important in titles and names.

Comment: @PaulStanley That is not the problem as I have to fiddle a lot inside biblatex. I just didn't think of the presented solution.

A really annoying problem is polyglossia not being compatible with the babel-option of biblatex. That meant a lot of manual if-clauses.

Answer (score 1):

@Audrey @PLK Using `usera` instead of `bookhyphenation` indeed fixes the problem.

Thank you very much.